# Afrikan Tähti improvements/variants

Tags: house-rules

A Finnish friend gave me a copy of [Afrikan Tähti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrikan_tahti). We played it a couple of times, and while it was kind of fun, it really seems like a children's game, and I won't bring it out again in a hurry. Luck overshadows strategy, and when you start you don't know if it will take 45 seconds or 45 minutes.

Are there any variants or house rules, or even different games that can be played with the same map and peices, that could be more strategic?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how much of an improvement this is but I found this:

http://www.witchmastercreations.com/board-game-mod-afrikan-zombeja-or-in-almost-english-afrikan-zombies/